# Problems with customization Xamarin.Forms.ListView

Tags: xamarin.forms

Problems in customization  Xamarin.Forms.ListView

Task:
    I need to implement a control for displaying items in GridView as on android.

The essence of the problem and attempt to implement it:
    I am created the class GridListBox  inherated from GridListBox Xamarin.Forms.ListView. The next i am created GridListBoxRenderer take for example Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ListViewRenderer

My GridListBox:

```
public class GridListBox : ListView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty ColumnCountProperty = BindableProperty.Create<GridListBox, int>(r => r.ColumnCount, 2);
        public int ColumnCount
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(ColumnCountProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ColumnCountProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty HorizontalSpacingProperty = BindableProperty.Create<GridListBox, int>(r => r.HorizontalSpacing, 5);
        public int HorizontalSpacing
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(HorizontalSpacingProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HorizontalSpacingProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty VerticalSpacingProperty = BindableProperty.Create<GridListBox, int>(r => r.VerticalSpacing, 5);
        public int VerticalSpacing
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(VerticalSpacingProperty); }
            set { SetValue(VerticalSpacingProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

Renderer for GridListBox:

```
public class GridListBoxRenderer:NativeRenderer
    {
        private Cell cellFocused;
        protected override void OnModelChanged(VisualElement oldModel, VisualElement newModel)
        {
            base.OnModelChanged(oldModel, newModel);

            var realListView = (GridView)Control;
            if (realListView == null)
            {
                realListView = new GridView(Context);
                SetNativeControl((View)realListView);
            }
            cellFocused = (Cell)null;
            realListView.Focusable = false;
            realListView.DescendantFocusability = DescendantFocusability.AfterDescendants;
            realListView.OnFocusChangeListener = (IOnFocusChangeListener)this;
            realListView.SetNumColumns(((Controls.GridListBox) newModel).ColumnCount);
            realListView.SetHorizontalSpacing(((Controls.GridListBox)newModel).HorizontalSpacing);
            realListView.SetVerticalSpacing(((Controls.GridListBox)newModel).VerticalSpacing);
            realListView.Adapter = new GridViewAdapter(Context, realListView, (Controls.GridListBox)newModel);
        }

        public override Size MinimumSize()
        {
            return new Size(40.0, 40.0);
        }
    }
```

And then the fun began: 
    Implementation GridViewAdapter is easy if take for example **Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ListViewAdapter (access as Internal)**.
To implement the public BaseAdapter.GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) with use ItemTemplate needs access to **Xamarin.Forms.ListView.TemplatedItems but it's Internal** ...

P.S.   How do developers from Xamarin planned to enable developers to customize Xamarin.Forms If most of the properties with internal access ...?

P.P.S. Similar difficulties have with customize the Xamarin.Forms.Page. The **Xamarin.Forms.Page.InternalChildren property is internal**

Comment: tell me about it! the Xamarin.Forms code is littered with internal stuff and hard-coded limitations (like Tap gesture only!)

Comment: One way I'm getting around their internal stuff is just copy-paste the code from their assembly into yours - it works for the most part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolving this issue is to use Reflection to access the internalization property

```
 public GridViewAdapter(Context context, GridView realListView, GridListBox gridListView)
            {
                _context = context;
                _realListView = realListView;
                _gridListView = gridListView;

                var info = _gridListView.GetType().GetProperty("TemplatedItems", BindingFlags.Instance |
                                BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                BindingFlags.Public);
                var item = info.GetValue(_gridListView);

                _templatedItemsList = item as IList;
                _templatedItemsINCC = item as INotifyCollectionChanged;

                _templatedItemsINCC.CollectionChanged += _templatedItemsINCC_CollectionChanged;
            }
```